Why Azure DevOps shows encoding change from utf-8 to Windows-1252?
We've noticed that for some users Azure DevOps in Pull Requests shows that encoding changes "utf-8 -> Windows-1252" (tooltip File encoding changed from utf-8 to Windows-1252). It happens only for few users and for some files.
In .editorconfig we have:
[*.cs]
charset = utf-8

So it's strange it isn't applied.
Do you know how to stop this incorrect encoding change (or detection)?
Is it Visual Studio or Azure DevOps bug?

Did you dig further into the habits of those users? Just ask them how they made those changes. While .editorconfig is widely adopted by editors and tools, there are things that don't support it well.

@Mattaniel, may i know if overriding the encoding(details below) work for you? Thanks.

It's not an issue from Azure DevOps since it doesn't happen for all users/files.
Try to ask the user to override the encoding for each single file by using "Save As" option for a check, please refer to the doc.

The coding format could be changed due to multiple reasons. For example:
When you add an EditorConfig file to your project in Visual Studio, only new lines of code are formatted based on the EditorConfig settings. The formatting of existing code isn't changed unless you run command like Code Cleanup.
Or there is another .editorconfig file to a folder in your file hierarchy, The new EditorConfig file settings apply to files at the same level and files in any subdirectories.
Or the user modified the file with other tools which changed the encoding.
Please check the official doc Define consistent coding styles with EditorConfig for more details.
